# check if regular language given CF grammar

Tags: regex, context-free-grammar, regular-language, computation-theory

I have this grammar
`S->aSbA
S->e 
A->aB 
B->bA`

How can i determine if the language is regular? My problem is that A and B doesnt have a terminal character so i dont know what languages it will produce.

Comment: You might wanna try that question on the [computer science stackexchange site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `e` is the empty word, right?

Comment: That language doesn't even terminate.  There is never a condition in which you're not looking for another symbol.

Comment: Technically speaking, the only string matched by that grammar is the empty string, so it's trivially regular. None of the productions other than `S -> e` is useful, since there is no base case for either `A` or `B`. I suppose you didn't manage to copy-and-paste the entire homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general method for this. Regularity is an undecidable problem for context-free languages.

In your specific case, as J Earls has pointed out, the only word you can derive is the empty word. All derivations that use a rule different from S -> e never terminate. Thus the language is finite and therefore regular.